# How to create a Fat Binary with armv6,armv7 and armv7s

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, xcode4.5

I want to support my app in all the older versions of iOS as well as new.  In the recent Xcode versions support for armv6 is dropped.  How can I build my app to support for armv6 ? Do I need to include armv7s to support all newer versions of iOS ?  Is it possible to create a binary that includes support for all of the 3 architectures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is just a link... I didn't try it..

"You can create an iOS binary that spans armv6 - armv7s with Xcode 4.5, but it takes some extra work .... You need to have multiple versions of Xcode installed ...."

**[ARMV6 SUPPORT WITH XCODE 4.5](http://cefaedfe.com/blog/2013/1/27/z8k2s46y4lvyv00scntkeyggoudlk5)**

Answer (score 3):

Can't be done. You either use newer versions of Xcode and get armv7/armv7s along with iOS 6.x support (and support back to iOS 4.3), or you use older versions of Xcode to get armv6/armv7 but not iOS 6.x APIs (but support back to iOS 3.1.3).

There are so few devices still using iOS prior to 4.3 that there is no sane reason to support those older versions.

If you REALLY must support everything, create two versions of the app. One with newer support and one with older support. Then watch as your download ratio is 1,000:1.

At some point soon, Apple will most likely drop support for new apps being created with older versions of Xcode. Apple likes to keep moving forward.